# Edit docx/xlsx/pptx file online(in browser) without storing file in cloud and save changes back to server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webforms, webdav, ms-wopi

Can you guys please help me in finding out how to edit microsoft documents online (in browser) without importing it to a cloudstroage and then saving back the changes to server.

Things to be noted:

1. I should be able to implement this in ASP.NET web forms.
2. No document should be stored over cloud.

Is webdav a better option compared to WOPI ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the browser edit experience that is in office online, you need to use Office Online Server installed on premise and the WOPI iframe that provides the office application.

More info can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server

If you do not wish to use sharepoint you need to provide another server to serve the files to the office online iframe.

One of the solutions is WOPI server that provides files for the office online server  iframe locally from your infrastructure - there are many avaliable a good starting point is:

https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. So now will i be able to run this on a normal windows server where i deploy my .net application and make it behave like a wopi host and then provide files to wopi client ?

Comment: yes, just like that. 
The components will be 
ASP.net application with iframe containing the WOPI iframe from OWAS

WOPI server that serves the files on specified urls and endpoints and acts like the file source for the OWAS

Office web application server (called Office online server now)